# JMSSerializer hasData deprecated

Tags: symfony, jms, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I have an entity with relatives paths. If those links are serialized, I want to change them to an absolute path.

```
class EntityA
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Serializer\Expose
     * @Serializer\Groups({"A"})
     */
    private $pathA;
}
```

I add an event subscribe on post_serialize. I can change the value of the field with

```
    $visitor->visitProperty(new StaticPropertyMetadata('', 'path_a', $absolutePath), $absolutePath);
```

BUT I don't that field if absolutePath wasn't in the groups A.

Before, I used $visitor->hasData('path_a') but it's now deprecated.

What's the new way to change path_a ONLY if it exists in the visitor:$data and don't break my serializer groups?

Comment: I have the same problem and I haven't found the solution. I just use `hasData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After  3.9.0 version  method hasData is not deprecated.

[CHANGELOG](https://github.com/schmittjoh/serializer/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#390-2020-08-26)